# How to find particular human parts on face in camera preview like Face Recognition - android

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, face-detection, face-recognition

My requirement is detected human lips(like Detect the particular human parts on their face) and show some lipstick color and apply the lipstick on their face while they are trying to take a selfie in through my app. (in this feature already available in the YouCameMakup app).

Now my problem is: I don't know the route path for where I start and which kind of technology or framework used for this kind of face recognition, So please tell me the route solution or similar kind of algorithm steps to complete.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might look into OpenCV.  It has numerous "computer vision" tools.  There's also OpenCV for Android...https://opencv.org/platforms/android/.  Might also be a task well-suited to machine-learning, presuming you can find an appropriate training set.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b You should write an answer as it seems to answer the question.